# Reapply decoration on content change in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm having an app using Monaco code editor and want to develop a global file content search like in VSCode in which the content in file will be highlighted when match the search result. I was able to highlight the text on load using createDecorationsCollection() function. However, when I alter the highlighted text the decoration for match result still exists. I tried to reapply the decoration collection in the onChange function but have no effect.

Here is my reproduce in Monaco playground: (not exact same code but same behavior)
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.35.0#XQAAAAIWBgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdOS8qlU4WDmTRXNuTfnoBAhm7hasbKCuA-Xn2CWEcQNiZX9dRgB3KMl-BI1jGRwtPOBIDGzuW9WZ9VdORjr3OcwtBD_-42y_2GMk2oMBr1q9GgH1n_Qsih50rZZUiDqoWsJUJmDF9P1zrYTI87qbVeqAz9xr5I_9fH9OrmHh1gnE_eee8BJoIRdMUagqgIZFocaM-nVqsMrBCDz0G5HshJduv8CVXaKgxFVXVZug6pyXXWVsKIS_AL2TClmk642lWLhQRHPZnyao0rjBNd0TwotOer3NXR905gel_LlXlRJeSBtDLRU0_5-zp3pjS9B1AF2qebN42tnT17Icqudi3RRiflD-lpUf_Vc9u0Kz-q3QR9WWUKpzjCZ9XhGukztTXsTmED5l6Sdmup0IJOW3KTTLXG51vfjxH1fDfSqPbSmflPIKKzDKQiwDMo8sURIUdsH9h5qOCLK8XTRlo6dvRuHfRifrM6CUpjdHJcoSJ39nLS0CLdBYMblVMKEfoazvcIkBPXKT_KnG6Ex1xy_7tjg1mK3RCsedd-xk_0JhaiK4FFpeli8d89yK1D5QOMDgtSmKzKb4aLiQez7Be9ZMYYaMhC2puvklZTqQAkdzDmfbwfJVV4InVhQTGv1zV33T4RxprJfCj0QEuqNiZKUxa28uoWKHy-tFxp1ZQp9AYlk7YLSQyBKWrRJwl9qgLIi856aod67XmmTl2VHYYh7M9kriHgkxrAG823wl8DMgeGIrqZIWLR56u7d2xrQz7l7lCXsONaFyAfkRJ9RHWqZ_dBMb0SJOuPg-lhDsiUC7aG3_8eeBiA